# Закрытие после клика

Tags: java, android

Первый клик- открытие.
Второй клик- закрытие. 
Третий клик - открытие. 
И тд.

```
while (countSchet % 2 == 0) 
{ 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = newArrayAdapter<String>(this android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList);//Создали адаптер для занесения в listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);    
    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    countSchet=+1;             
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(newAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {
       @Override            
       //Обрабатываем нажатие на элемент
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<>parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) 
       {
           TextView textView = (TextView)itemClicked;   
           String strText = textView.getText().toString();                  
           mEditText.setText(strText);//меняем mEditText
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Файл сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           toast.show();
           listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           return;
       }
    });

}

while (countSchet % 2 != 0) 
{
    listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    countSchet=+1;
    return;
}
```

Comment: А в чем, собственно, вопрос?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мой магический шар говорит, что у вас опечатка тут:

> countSchet = +1;

Вы вместо увеличения на единицу присваиваете `+1`, т.е. вам надо использовать оператор `+=` или вообще `++`:

```
countSchet += 1;
//или
//countSchet++;
```

Answer (score 2):

А лучше использовать флаги, если true 
(т.е. окно активно: listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Иначе listView.setVisibility(View.Visible);

Суть, думаю, вы поняли